# How to handle thousands of background jobs?

Tags: java, algorithm, quartz-scheduler

We are using quartz for a background server whose purpose is to systematically aggregate the data by applying some business rules. Essentially, we have three background jobs which fires m*n more jobs. Since we are a SaaS application so we have multiple tenants so we end up with (no. of tenants * (3 + m*n )) jobs. These are fired over ten threads and the triggers repeat indefinitely as we require them to be aggregated hourly due to business constraints. Note that once these jobs are fired at server startup they remain consistent, i.e. no new jobs would come. SO the final number of jobs are as mentioned above.

Each job hits the DB and some of them could take more than a second as well.

Could any of you suggest the best way to scale this. We could consider restructuring the code as well as this code was more of a POC and we really need to SCALE!!!

----------------------EDIT----------------------
From the responses so far received I would like to make the question more concise. There is this approach which we followed, i.e. using 10 threads we scheduled multiple quartz job at server startup and triggered them indefinitely to be run every hour. Do any of the members here have a suggestion here how to approach such problems in a more efficient manner, is quartz scheduler the best approach or use some other tools/ framework, maybe Spring batch..

Comment: Do you need to fire so many jobs?  Can you not fire a job which in turn calls your `m` tasks or `m*n` tasks?  If you can combine these tasks you might find you use resources more efficiently.

Comment: No, these jobs are all created during server startup. Each job represents a task which has to be done periodically every hour. So the current design creates these tasks at a go and do this over and over again.

Comment: So you create n*m tasks to be run every hour.  Why not have one job run ever hour which performs n*m tasks?

Comment: You should not start each job as a single thread. Group them and launch in few threads.